# Assigning new vectors in a dataframe using cbind () and data.frame()

Tags: r

I am putting vectors into a dataframe using cbind() and data.frame(). And I want to add a new vector (price/money) when I build the dataframe.

flowers1 : 
  using data.frame() to create a dataframe ;
  '=' to assign the new vector

flowers2 : 
  using cbind() to create a dataframe ;
  '=' to assign the new vector

flowers3 : 
    using data.frame() to create a dataframe;
    '<-' to assign the new vector

flowers4 : 
    using cbind() to create a dataframe;
    '<-' to assign the new vector

flowers1 and 2 are what I expect but in flowers3, the header of the third column is odd. And in flowers4, the header of the third column is missing.

**My questions are:**

1. what caused this?
2. Is there any other difference between assigning vector using '<-' and '='

   (I only know these two assign methods have different priority and different variable life time ?
3. Is it illegal or not recommended to assign a new vector when creating a dataframe?

Thanks!

```
name <- c('iris','daisy')
color <- c('purple','blue')
flowers1 <- data.frame(name,color,price = c(10,20))
flowers1
# output
name  color price
1  iris purple    10
2 daisy   blue    20

flowers2 <- cbind(name,color,price = c(10,20))
flowers2
# output
name    color    price
[1,] "iris"  "purple" "10" 
[2,] "daisy" "blue"   "20"

flowers3 <- data.frame(name,color,price <- c(10,20))
flowers3
# output
   name  color price....c.10..20.
1  iris purple                 10
2 daisy   blue                 20

flowers4 <- cbind(name,color,money <- c(10,20))
flowers4
# output
      name    color        
[1,] "iris"  "purple" "10"
[2,] "daisy" "blue"   "20"
```

Comment: You can use the `<-` in `within`, but in `cbind`, `data.frame`, it should be `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use = to set function arguments, and <- as assignment operator. This could explain a little:

```
A = LETTERS[1:5]
B = letters[1:5]

d <- data.frame(A , B, CC <- seq(5, 1, -1))
d
CC # lives outside d!

d1 <- data.frame(A, B, DD = seq(5, 1, -1))
d1
DD # does not live outside d1
```